# Null value is also decoding in HIVE

Tags: hive, null, decode, translate

I am working on Hive. I need decode some of the fields in table so i am using `Translate()` method but problem is like in some of the places i have `null` this character also decoding. How do you solve this one?

here is my code

`TRANSLATE (Address2,
                  'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz',
                  'DEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZABCdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzabc') as Address2,`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use a `CASE` block

```
Select
    CASE WHEN Address2 IS NOT NULL  THEN
      TRANSLATE (Address2,
                  'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz',
                  'DEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZABCdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzabc') 
     END as 
Address2
```